# Xcode 4 Archive build not finding imports in precompiled headers

Tags: ios, build, xcode4, archive

I have a project which won't Archive-build correctly in Xcode 4.  It appears to me that the "Build For Archiving" and "Archive" commands build differently, and I cannot determine any reason why!

Details:

- The workspace contains two projects: an app and a static library; the projects are arranged as peers.
- "Build" and "Run" both work correctly; app executes in iOS simulator and on device.
- "Build for Running", "Build for Testing", "Build for Profiling", and "Build for Archiving" all work correctly also.

  - Build for Running is debug, Build for Profiling is release, so both configuration have been tested.
- "Archive" fails!

Failure 1 (Library):
When I try to execute the "Archive" command on the library, a custom resource script fails.  The script is reading from the resources directory ($RESOURCES_DIR)

For release builds, this maps to:

> ...DerivedData/App-uniquecrap/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Resources/LibraryName

For the archive, this maps to:

> ...DerivedData/App-uniquecrap/ArchiveIntermediates/Build Frameworks/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Resources/LibraryName

Except `Resources` is missing in the `ArchiveIntermediates` tree!

UPDATE: The first part of the problem is caused by poor quoting in the script file.  Xcode4's paths now include a folder with an embedded space (imagine that!) and improperly quotes paths don't work as well as we would like.  That fixed, I still have the problem that the resource files copied by the Gather Resources build phase are not going to the correct location; the script expects them in $(RESOURCE_DIR), but I can't seem to find the correct setting in Gather Resources to send them there.  Suggestions?

Failure 2 (App):
When I have managed to kludge my way part the first failure (typically by copying files and bypassing the script), I run into another error building the App.  "Archive" complains that it can't find imported files when building the precompiled headers.

Nothing unusual here either; headers are imported in pch file in the typical manner:

```
#import <LibraryName/Library.h>
```

As before, "Build", "Build for Archiving", etcetera succeed without problem.  "Archive" fails.  Either the include paths are set up correctly and "Archive" is ignoring them; or the include paths are set up incorrectly and Xcode is auto-magically fixing them in the other builds.  (Either way, I'm very frustrated).

How can I (A) make Archive builds work; or (B) figure out what is going on, so I can accomplish (A)?

Thanks.